# AWS Auto-Scaling with existing data files and folders

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to transfer data files and folders to newly created server(s) at the time Auto-Scaling in AWS?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a way to update your server with some data files and folders when it spinup with auto-scaling.

You have two option.

- [Create Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html) of the existing server ( if the data is supposed to static and did not change) and launch the new instance from the Autoscaling group from this [AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html).
- Place files and folder on s3 and pull the files and folder from s3 during launch time using [user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Comment: how to transfer websites at the time spin up server due to auto scaling in AWS

Comment: pull the latest code from the git, if you are interested to always new code when server spinup.